# How to get node to exit when mongo connect fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'd like my Node JS app to exit immediately if it can't connect to Mongo. I'm using the `mongodb` node library.

I've reduced the code down to

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017');
```

If Mongo is **not** running, I get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` with `ECONNREFUSED`, which I fully expect, but then the program hangs and never exits. This is with Node version 10.0.0.

Since the connection never succeeded I don't have a connection handle to close. I've tried various ways to `catch` the rejected promise, but I have been unsuccessful in getting the program to exit.

What do I need to do to shut down the MongoClient and make the program exit in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your application is remaining alive because it is trying to [reconnect](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/MongoClient.html#.connect).  You can try disabling the recconect:

```js
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', {
  autoReconnect: false
}, (err, client) => {
  if (client) client.close();
});
```

Or, you can terminate the process using [`process.exit(1)`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) to kill the program.

```js
const {
  MongoClient
} = require('mongodb');

// Callback syntax
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', (err, db) => {
  if (err) process.exit(1);
});

// Promise syntax
MongoClient
  .connect('mongodb://localhost:27017')
  .catch(err => {
    process.exit(1);
  });

// Async/await syntax
(async function() {
  let db;
  try {
    db = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017');
  } catch (err) {
    process.exit(1);
  }
}());
```

Comment: `process.exit()` of any kind will of course exit the program. But worth noting that the "not closing" in the context of the question actually has nothing to do with the driver itself, and will be because of other things ( likely http listener ) still being active on the event loop. On a "connection refused" error all of the above code would actually exit by itself "without" explicitly calling the `process.exit()`, since "by itself" there is nothing the driver keeps on the event loop on fatal error condition such as this.

Comment: @NeilLunn I just finished adding a note about reconnect.  Does that address your concerns or should I be more explicit?

Comment: I'm actually not talking about reconnect at all there, but it is worth adding in the answer as you have since you should realistically do that. I believe the context of the question is "at program start" and not "as program is running" anyway. And it's that "at program start" which I'm actually talking about in the conditions. The "driver" is not actually responsible for stopping node from exiting, as "other" routines actually have things still registered on the event loop and, NOT the driver. Not saying it's "incorrect" to call `process.exit()`, just "misleading" that the "driver" needs this.

Comment: Thanks, `autoReconnect` did it. And yes, I meant to say at program start.

Comment: I'm curious why it should be trying to reconnect in this way, since it's not obvious to me how you would get a hold of the connection if, sometime after the initial fail, it ever did manage to connect.

Comment: I found your excellent reply but I'm having issues with it, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54737280/catch-fails-on-connection-to-mongo